# Customize how dolhpin folders are displayed (for each folder)

Tags: dolphin

I would like to view the home folder with large icons, while all the other folders with small icons and detailed layout, **without using hotkeys or using the menu buttons**.

**So I would like to customize dolphin view for specific folders.**

It's possible to do it? How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify your Ubuntu version, I show how to do it in 22.04, but I believe this should work in all other recent versions of Ubuntu in the same way.

First switch to detailed view (#1 in the picture) since this is the view you want to use with most folders. Then click the hamburger menu icon (#2 in the picture), choose `Configure` from the popup menu (#3 in the picture) and choose `Configure Dolphin` in the next popup menu (#4 in the picture).

[image]

Now the `Configure - Dolphin` window is open, here choose `General`,choose the `Behavior`-tab, select `Remember display style for each folder`and hit the `Apply`-button.

[image]

Now back in the dolphin window visit your home folder and switch the view to compact view. Done, now your home folder will be displayed with larger icons in compact view while all other folders will be displayed with smaller icons in detailed view.

[image]

As a side note: In the configuration window you can define the defaults for the different display styles when you choose `View Modes` from the side bar.